Calculating Eigenkets of Perturbed Matrix for Second-Order Correction
Q: Find the eigenvalues of the 3x3 symmetric matrix $H$ using perturbation theory where all of the elements on the diagonal of $H$ are an order greater than the elements not on the diagonal.
We can begin by decomposing this Hamiltonian into unperturbed and perturbed Hamiltonians, as follows
$$H = H^0 + \lambda H^1.$$
Since all of the diagonal elements of $H$ are an order of magnitude greater than the non-diagonal elements, it is convenient to decompose $H$ such that all of its diagonal elements are contained in $H^0$ and all of the non-diagonal elements are contained in $H^1$. Because $H$ is symmetric, therefore $H^1$ is symmetric (and $H^0$ is trivially symmetric because it is diagonal).
We can use the following equation from perturbation theory to find the first-order correction:
$$\label{first_order}E_n^{(1)} = \langle n^0|H^1|n^0 \rangle.$$
Because $H^0$ is diagonal, its eigenkets, $n^0$, are extremely straightforward to find: they are the three ortho-normal basis vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
Now, we proceed to calculate the second-order correction. From Shankar, the second order perturbation can be calculated using the equation
$$E_n^{(2)} = \langle n^0 | H^1 | n^1 \rangle.$$
Since $H^1$ is a non-diagonal matrix, its eigenkets are much more difficult to find. I know that we could find its eigenkets by using numerical software, such as Mathematica. However, in this exercise I think the intent is not to use such software.
Therefore, is there a more elegant way to either calculate $n^1$ or perhaps alternate method to calculate $E_n^{(2)}$ without relying on numerical software? It seems like $H^1$ having the property of being a symmetric matrix may come in useful here.

You made an arithmetic error. The eigenkets of $H^1$ are not those 3 that you wrote down.

"I use the following equation from perturbation theory to find the first-order correction... How can I calculate the eigenvalues of this matrix more accurately?" How about checking the second-order correction...

@naturallyInconsistent I fixed OP's typo

@hft that makes much more sense. I need my morning tea

While the equation for the second-order correction
\begin{equation}
E_n^{(2)} = \langle n^0 | H^1 | n^1 \rangle
\end{equation}
Is correct, I found that it is more useful to put that equation in its more common and more useful form
$$
\begin{align}
E_n^{(2)} &= \sum_{m, m \ne n} \frac{\langle n^0 | H^1 | m^0 \rangle \langle m^0|H^1 | n^0 \rangle}{E_n ^{(0)} - E_m^{(0)}}\\
&= \sum_{m, m \ne n} \frac{|\langle n^0|  H^1 | m^0 \rangle|^2}{E_n^{(0)} - E_m^{(0)}}
\end{align}
$$
Where I have followed the steps from Shankar's textbook
